# Xen 4.1 + NVidia driver = Unity has no window decorations

Tags: 11.10, unity, nvidia, window-manager, xen

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity. I installed XEN and booted its kernel. The machine booted normally. However, when I started Unity (3D), there were no window decorations.

I tried Unity 2D and the window decorations are present there. I then decided to remove the driver (installed through Additional Drivers) and install it manually like this:

```
IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=y CC="gcc -DNV_VMAP_4_PRESENT -DNV_SIGNAL_STRUCT_RLIM" ./NVIDIA*
```

...but the window decorations were still missing in Unity 3D. The window decorations are there when I boot the regular Ubuntu kernel (without XEN support).

What could be the problem and how to fix it?